# multiple backgroundworker queueing

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous, backgroundworker

in my winforms app, I have a Queue which contains objects:

```
    Queue<MyObj> _queuedRows = new Queue<MyObj>();
```

For each object, I must start a separate backgroundworker to do some timeconsuming job.

```
    private void DoAll(List<MyObj> lst)
    {
        foreach (MyObj o in lst)
        {
            _queuedRows.Enqueue(o);
        }

        while (_queuedRows.Any())
            DoSingle();
    }

    private void DoSingle()
    {
        if (!isCancelPending())
        {
            if (_queuedRows.Any())
            {
                MyObj currentObj = _queuedRows.Dequeue();
                InitBackgroundWorker(currentObj);
            }
        }
    }

    private void InitBackgroundWorker(MyObj currentObj)
    {
        BackgroundWorker _worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        _worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        _worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        _worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
        _worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(worker_RunWorkerCompleted);

        if (!_worker.IsBusy && currentObj != null)
            _worker.RunWorkerAsync(currentObj);
    }
```

My problem is, after the call to RunWorkerAsync, the execution jumps to the next iteration of the while (which is logical, as the worker is running async and it allows for the next iteration to happen).

What I actually need to do, is to tell the app somehow to WAIT until the backgroundworker has completed the job, and only then should it start the next iteration by continuing with calling DoSingle().

Should I apply a lock on the _queuedRows object or something similar? Thanks,

Comment: Do you have to use a background worker? Using Tasks would be a very nice solution to this. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235608

Comment: Thank you for the link, its very useful, didnt know about that. The BackgroundWorker is not mandatory, it was something I thought of as a way to prevent blocking the UI while the app works.

Comment: Yeah, BackgroundWorker is good for fast and simple applications to prevent UI from blocking. For anything more advanced, use tasks. TPL in .net 4 is awesome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of calling `DoSingle` in the while loop, change it to call `DoSingle` once and then in the background worker's `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler call `DoSingle` again and again until the queue is done.

```
    private void DoAll(List<MyObj> lst)
    {
        foreach (MyObj o in lst)
        {
            _queuedRows.Enqueue(o);
        }

        if (_queuedRows.Any())
            DoSingle();
    }
```

Also since you're not processing all objects in the queue in parallel, instantiate background worker only once and reuse it.

Answer (score 0):

You must use only one backgroundworker.